# What's the Do Loop Equivalent for C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I made a calendar in VB.Net and I decided to give C# a try. I am confused on how to convert my code to C# because of the **Do Loop**.
Here is my current source code in VB.

```
    Public Sub LoadCal(ByVal ldate As Date, ByVal Selected As Integer)


    M = ldate.Month
    Y = ldate.Year
    D = ldate.Day

    clearall()
    MonthName.Text = monthstr(ldate.Month) & " " & ldate.Year
    Dim fdate As DayOfWeek = GetFirstOfMonthDay(ldate)
    Dim idate As Integer = 1
    Dim row As Integer = 1

    Do
        getlabel(fdate, row).Text = idate
        getlabel(fdate, row).ForeColor = Label18.ForeColor

        'Current Date
        If idate = Selected And idate = Date.Now.Day And ldate.Month = Date.Now.Month Then
            getlabel(fdate, row).ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If

        If fdate = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
            row += 1
        End If

        fdate = tdate(fdate)
        idate += 1

        If su1.Text.Length = 0 Then
            psu1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            psu1.Enabled = False
        Else
            psu1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            psu1.Enabled = True
        End If

        If idate = Date.DaysInMonth(ldate.Year, ldate.Month) + 1 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

And here's what I made into C# that seems to be correct. (I hope)

```
public void LoadCal(DateTime ldate, int Selected) {
    M = ldate.Month;
    Y = ldate.Year;
    D = ldate.Day;

    clearall();
    MonthName.Text = (monthstr(ldate.Month) + (" " + ldate.Year));
    DayOfWeek fdate = GetFirstOfMonthDay(ldate);
    int idate = 1;
    int row = 1;

    ) {
        getlabel(fdate, row).Text = idate;
        getlabel(fdate, row).ForeColor = Label18.ForeColor;
        // Current Date
        Now.Month;
        getlabel(fdate, row).ForeColor = Color.Red;
        fdate = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
        row++;
        if ((fdate == tdate(fdate))) {
            idate++;
            if ((su1.Text.Length == 0)) {
                psu1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                psu1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else {
                psu1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                psu1.Enabled = true;
            }

            (DaysInMonth(ldate.Year, ldate.Month) + 1);
                       }            
    }        
}
```

I'm pretty sure C# doesn't accept VB's For Loop and I don't get how to incorporate it in another way. I appreciate the help and sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `do {...} while (...);`

**Example!**

```
 public class TestDoWhile 
    {
        public static void Main () 
        {
            int x = 0;
            do 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                x++;
            } while (x < 5);
        }
    }
    /*
        Output:
        0
        1
        2
        3
        4
    */
```

And if you wish to get out of the loop (like you did in your code), just use the `break;` keyword.

In your case, you will `do {...} while (true);` because you actually want your code to loop continuously until you `break`.

Comment: Oh wow now I feel stupid. I really REALLY appreciate the help. I have another question and it's a bit related. What's the Module counterpart of C#? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @SlicedBread, there isn't one. `static class` is the closest you get to a VB module in C#.

Comment: I see. Looks like the transition won't be easy. Thank you very much, @KirillShlenskiy.

Answer (score 2):

```
do
{
   // Body
} while (condition);
```

It's called the `do..while` in C#.

Here, the condition needs to be a expression checking that returns a bool value.  One thing to **note** here, is that a `do` loop will always execute atleast once.

Comment: Do always runs once regardless of programming language, I do believe; but valid point to those who don't know that.

Comment: @Edward Just stating the obvious ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know but @SlicedBread may asked for infinite loop in c# AS Yotam Salmon already explained while syntax :

```
'VB .Net
Do
Loop While condition

//in C#
do 
{
} while (condition); 

'VB .Net
Do While condition
Loop 

//in C#
while (condition) 
{
}


'and as asked - infinite loop
'VB .Net
Do 
Loop 
//in C#
do 
{
} while (true); 

//and use break; for exit do but it is not exact replacement
```

@SlicedBread you could simply convert code on any online code converter to check for syntax

here is converted code ---

```
public void LoadCal(System.DateTime ldate, int Selected)
{

    M = ldate.Month;
    Y = ldate.Year;
    D = ldate.Day;

    clearall();
    MonthName.Text = monthstr(ldate.Month) + " " + ldate.Year;
    DayOfWeek fdate = GetFirstOfMonthDay(ldate);
    int idate = 1;
    int row = 1;

    do {
        getlabel(fdate, row).Text = idate;
        getlabel(fdate, row).ForeColor = Label18.ForeColor;

        //Current Date
        if (idate == Selected & idate == System.DateTime.Now.Day & ldate.Month == System.DateTime.Now.Month) {
            getlabel(fdate, row).ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        if (fdate == DayOfWeek.Saturday) {
            row += 1;
        }

        fdate = tdate(fdate);
        idate += 1;

        if (su1.Text.Length == 0) {
            psu1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            psu1.Enabled = false;
        } else {
            psu1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            psu1.Enabled = true;
        }

        if (idate == System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(ldate.Year, ldate.Month) + 1) {
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit Do
        }
    } while (true);
}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```